# How to invoke the remove() method?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I am testing the models in zend project, I have a question about how to  invoke the remove() method?

this is the find method I am testing:

```
<?

class Admin_Model_Member2 extends Custom_Model_Base {


    protected function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }



    static function load($id) {
        return self::_selectAndBind(
                get_class(),
                        self::getDefaultAdapter()
                        ->select()
                        ->from('member')
                        ->where('id = ?', array($id)),
                true);
    }



    function remove() {
        return $this->delete();
    }



}
```

Admin_Model_Member2 extends Custom_Model_Base, this is the Custom_Model_Base,

```
abstract class Custom_Model_Base    { 
static public function init($default_adapter = null)
    {
        if (self::$_db_default === null)
        {
            if (!is_null($default_adapter))
            {
                if (!$default_adapter instanceof Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract)
                {
                    throw new Exception('Provided adapter does not extend Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract');
                }
                self::$_db_default = $default_adapter;
            }
            else if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered('db'))
            {
                self::$_db_default = Zend_Registry::get('db');
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception('No default adapter provided for the model layer');
            }

        }
    }

 public function delete()
    {
        $where = array();
        foreach($this->_primary as $column)
        {
            $where[$column] = $this->_data[$column];
        }

        if ($this->_db->delete($this->_table, $where) != 0)
        {
            foreach($this->_primary as $column)
            {
                $this->_data[$column] = null;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is the test case I write,

```
public function testCanRemove() {
        $data = "80176";
            Admin_Model_Member2::init();
        $this->_model = Admin_Model_Member2::load($data);
        $this->assertTrue($this->_model->remove());
    }
```

I want to test remove() method, so I load($id) a object, but when I invoke $this->_model->remove(), it tells me " Call to a member function delete() on a non-object" in 113 of class Custom_Model_Base which is "if ($this->_db->delete($this->_table, $where) != 0)", what is the problem and how to invoke the remove() method?
Admin_Model_Member2::init() can not be called in constructor of Admin_Model_Member2, because the constructor is protected.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228)

Answer (score 1):

$this->_db is not initialized in Custom_Model_Base.  You need to call Admin_Model_Member2::init() at some point before you try to delete the record.  Perhaps in the constructor of Admin_Model_Member2.